# How to Implement Tensorflow Model Parallelism in Asynchronous Actor Critic Methods ?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am using A3C architecture with 100 parallel threads. I have 2 Nvidia 1080ti cards. But my initial model is running on a single GPU. With some extensions, my new model is too heavy to run on a single card. Since A3C method is Asynchronous model-free RL method I used model parallelism. Which means I used **tf.device()** to distributed different operations in my two GPUs. But I observed it is **very slow and most of the times operation got failed.**

- Is there a desired way to implement model parallelism without changing the original architecture of A3C?